# How to set the BindableLayout.ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection in an other file

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently i have a TasksGroupPageViewModel.cs that contains my two ObservableCollection:

```
public ObservableCollection<TasksGroup> TasksGroups { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<TasksGroup>();
public ObservableCollection<Tasks> Taches1 { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Tasks>();
```

The binding for my CollectionView which uses the TasksGroups data works, BUT i have a bindable stacklayout inside it but i am unable to bind it to his ObservableCollection data (taches1)

**From the debuger i can see that it always try to access data from Models.TasksGroup.cs and not Models.Tasks.cs, it's like since my stacklayout is a children of the CollectionView, i can't bind to it**

**My question is : How can i directly bind to Taches1 ObservableCollection which is in TaskGroupPageViewModel with BindableLayout.ItemsSource="" or in .xaml.cs file but i didn't find a way to do it like i did for TasksGroup in the on appearing method**

**How i initialize my data in TaskGroupPage.xaml.cs (data1 is for TasksGroup and data2 is for Tasks :**

```
 protected override async void OnAppearing()
   {
        base.OnAppearing();

        var data2 = await App.Database.GetAllTasks();
        var data1 = await App.Database.GetTaskGroupsAsync();

        var vm = this.BindingContext as TasksGroupPageViewModel;
        vm.TasksGroups = new ObservableCollection<TasksGroup>(data1);
        TasksGroupCollection.ItemsSource = vm.TasksGroups;
    
        vm.Taches1 = new ObservableCollection<Tasks>(data2);
}
```

**How i bind to my collection view with x:Name=TasksGroupCollection**

```
        <CollectionView Grid.Row="2" Margin="25" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                SelectionMode="Single" x:Name="TasksGroupCollection" >
```

**Inside this CollectionView i have a bindable stack layout which i want to bind to Taches1 data**

```
                                      <StackLayout Grid.Column="2" Spacing="10" >
                                                <Label Text="Tâches" TextColor="Black" FontSize="15" Margin="20,0"/>
                                                <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding }"  HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="20,0,0,20" x:Name="Taches1">
                                                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate >


                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                            <Label TextColor="#2F3246" FontSize="12">
                                                                <Label.FormattedText>
                                                                    <FormattedString>
                                                                        <FormattedString.Spans>
                                                                            <Span Text="{Binding TaskDBA}"/>
                                                                            <Span Text=" - "/>
                                                                            <Span Text="{Binding TaskDescription}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                                                        </FormattedString.Spans>
                                                                    </FormattedString>
                                                                </Label.FormattedText>
                                                            </Label>


                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate >
                                                </StackLayout>

                                                
                                            </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From the debuger i can see that it always try to access data from
> Models.TasksGroup.cs and not Models.Tasks.cs

When any element is included in a `DataTemplate`, the `BindingContext` will be the current item from the template's ItemsSource.

Your `TasksGroupCollection.ItemsSource` is `vm.TasksGroups` and there is no property called `Taches1` in `vm.TasksGroups`, that's why you can't bind successfully.

**Solution:**

`Taches1` is a property of `vm` and you should set the correct binding Source:

First, give a name to your ContentPage, let's say it MyPage:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"

             x:Name="MyPage"

             x:Class="App266.MainPage">
```

Then the `bindingContext` of your page is `vm`, bind the `BindableLayout.ItemsSource` to `vm.Taches1` :

```
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding BindingContext.Taches1 , Source={x:Reference MyPage}}"  HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="20,0,0,20" x:Name="Taches1">
```